# Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.search() with exact value

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any syntax can let me search with exact value? ( Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.search())

I have a component with attribute

attributeName:"Level"

displayValue:"Level 1"

and another component with

attributeName:"Level"

displayValue:"Level 2"

when i search

```
  model.search("Level 1", function (idArray) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(dbIdArrayResult, idArray);
    }, function () { }, [attributeName]);
```

it will return both components. I want the search result will match exactly with the value.

Comment: did yo try "Level " (with quotes)? the space at the end should force an exact match.

Comment: It works~~~ thank you~~

Comment: great, reposted as an answer... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use quotes and add a space at the end, which should force an exact match.

> "Level "